# High softirq issue in a tunneled setup

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn, tunnel

While trying to find the source of a high softirq problem in a OpenVPN setup, I launched two VMs (A & B) on a cloud host in same location. I also configured private networking on both of them. I then established 2 IPIP tunnels between these two VMs using both public(eth0) & private interfaces(eth1).

```
A.A.A.A = A's public IP on eth0
B.B.B.B = B's public IP on eth0
a.a.a.a = A's private IP on eth1 (provided by host for private networking)
b.b.b.b = B's private IP on eth1 (provided by host for private networking)
```

Tunnels were established like this:

```
ip tunnel add pub0 mode ipip local A.A.A.A remote B.B.B.B ttl 255
ip addr add 10.0.1.1/30 dev pub0 
ip link set pub0 up

ip tunnel add pub0 mode ipip local B.B.B.B remote A.A.A.A ttl 255
ip addr add 10.0.1.2/30 dev pub0 
ip link set pub0 up

ip tunnel add pvt0 mode ipip local a.a.a.a remote b.b.b.b ttl 255
ip addr add 10.0.2.1/30 dev pvt0 
ip link set pvt0  up

ip tunnel add pvt0 mode ipip local b.b.b.b remote a.a.a.a ttl 255
ip addr add 10.0.2.2/30 dev pvt0 
ip link set pvt0 up
```

A & B are connected in 4 ways now:

```
A.A.A.A <=> B.B.B.B (public IPs on eth0)
a.a.a.a <=> b.b.b.b (private IPs on eth1 provided by host)
10.0.1.1 <=> 10.0.1.2 (ipip tunnel via eth0)
10.0.2.1 <=> 10.0.2.2 (ipip tunnel via eth1)
```

I then performed iperf3 tests between them keeping A as server and B as client while monitoring the si (softirq) value in top on A:

```
A.A.A.A <=> B.B.B.B = normal si between 0-4% @ ~2Gbits/sec throughput
b.b.b.b <=> b.b.b.b = normal si between 0-4% @ ~2Gbits/sec throughput 
10.0.1.1 <=> 10.0.1.2 = si shoots to 30-45% @ ~2Gbits/sec throughput
10.0.2.1 <=> 10.0.2.2 = normal si between 0-3% @ ~500Mbits/sec throughput
```

I am intrigued by both 3rd & 4th tests. Why would CPU usage shoot to that level when the data is received over pub0 (ipip tunnel via eth0) but not on pvt0 (ipip tunnel via eth1) and can this be solved? I don't understand why the throughput got reduced by 1/4th while performing the test on tunnel established via private networking (eth1) in comparison to pub0. It could be something host related. I am more concerned about that high softirq issue.

**Is this high softirq normal when the data is transferred over a tunnel instead of public interfaces? And if that is so, why did it not happen in the 10.0.2.1 <=> 10.0.2.2 (pvt0) test as that too is a ipip tunnel.**

Comment: @DavidPostill can you please move it out of hold. I have added some direct questions to all of the context above.